Confused about this usage of 前半 here

だが彼女の持つ責任の重さから鑑みて７桁前半の権限は持っているのではないか。しかも領収書無しの。

The character is speaking about his boss and how she, being his boss, has less limit on the department spending compared to them.
I know the sentence is "taking in account her important position, she holds a huge spending power and she doesn't need to show  receipts".
However, I'm not sure what "桁前半の" means. The "first half of a seven row column"? Is he saying that, for example, if she has 1.000.000 then she can change what she wants about the last 3 digits?

Numbers are counted from 1, 2, 3... to 9. So smaller numbers come earlier, and bigger ones come later. With this framing, 前半 means that the most significant digit has a "lower half" figure (vice versa for 後半).
In US, I think you can refer to "low seven figures" of money, but unlike English low / mid / high partition, the Japanese language most naturally divides the range in two halves. Thus the phrase is telling that she has a power to move roughly 1,000,000—5,000,000 units (yen?) of money at her disposal.
